# Three integrals in Peskin's Textbook

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, integration, calculus

Peskin's QFT textbook

1.page 14

$$\int_0 ^\infty \mathrm{d}p\ p \sin px \ e^{-it\sqrt{p^2 +m^2}}$$

when $x^2\gg t^2$, how do I apply the method of stationary phase to get the book's answer.

2.page 27

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}p\frac{p\ e^{ipr}}{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}$$

where $r>0$

3.page 27

$$\int_{m}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}E \sqrt{E^2-m^2}e^{-iEt}$$

where $m>0$

I'm crazy about these integrals, but the textbook doesn't give the progress.

Comment: Hey, what about Mr. Schroeder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**1.** Since $x\gg p$, we see that $\sin(px)$ is highly oscillatory. In fact, the integral becomes

$$\int_0 ^\infty \mathrm{d}p\ p \sin px \ e^{-it\sqrt{p^2 +m^2}}\sim \int_{-\infty} ^\infty \mathrm{d}p\ p\ e^{ipx-it\sqrt{p^2 +m^2}}$$

modulo some factor of $\pm2/i$. Observe now this integral resembles $\int f(p)\exp(g(p))\,\mathrm{d}p$. We find the point $\tilde{p}$ such that

$$g'(\tilde{p})=0.$$

Then just replace $g(p)$ with $g(\tilde{p})+\frac{1}{2}g''(\tilde{p})(p-\tilde{p})^{2}$ and carry out the integral as a moment of a Gaussian. For more on this approximation, see e.g. the relevant chapter of Hunter and Nachtergaele's book (freely and legally [available](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m204/ch3.pdf)).

**2.** This is just a Fourier transform of $p\,(p^{2}+m^{2})^{-1/2}$.

**3.** I assume you are referring to Eq (2.51) on page 27. We write the integral as

$$I(t) = \int^{\infty}_{m}\sqrt{E^{2}-m^{2}}e^{-iEt}\,\mathrm{d}E.$$

Peskin and Schroeder consider this integral as $t\to\infty$. If we consider a change of variables to

$$E^{2}-m^{2}=\mu^{2}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \mathrm{d}E = \frac{\mu}{\sqrt{m^{2}+\mu^{2}}}\mathrm{d}\mu$$

We have

\begin{align}
I(t) &= \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\mu^{2}}{\sqrt{m^{2}+\mu^{2}}}e^{-it\sqrt{m^{2}+\mu^{2}}}\mathrm{d}\mu \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\mu^{2}}{\sqrt{m^{2}+\mu^{2}}}e^{-it\sqrt{m^{2}+\mu^{2}}}\mathrm{d}\mu
\end{align}

Let

$$f(\mu) = \frac{\mu^{2}}{\sqrt{m^{2}+\mu^{2}}},\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\phi(\mu) = \sqrt{m^{2}+\mu^{2}}$$

so

$$I(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(\mu)e^{-it\phi(\mu)}\mathrm{d}\mu.$$

Observe

$$f(\mu)=\mu\phi'(\mu).$$

As $t\to\infty$, the integral becomes highly oscillatory.

There are two ways to approach the problem from here. The first, unforgivably handwavy but faster: take the stationary phase approximation, and pretend that $f(\mu_{\text{crit}})$ is some arbitrary constant.

The critical points for $\phi$ are $\mu_{0}=0$ and $\mu_{\pm}=\pm im$. We only care about the real $\mu$, so we Taylor expand about $\mu_0$ to second order:

\begin{align}
\phi(\mu)&=\phi(0)+\frac{1}{2!}\phi''(0)\mu^{2}\\
&=m + \frac{1}{2m}\mu^{2}
\end{align}

We now approximate the integral as

$$I(t) \sim \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(c)e^{-itm}e^{-it\mu^{2}/2m}\mathrm{d}\mu \approx f(c)e^{-itm}\sqrt{\frac{4\pi m}{t}}.\tag{1}$$

The other approximation doesn't fix $f$. Observe $f(\mu)\sim|\mu|$, so we have

$$I(t) \sim e^{-itm} \int^{\infty}_{0}\mu e^{-it\mu^{2}/2m}\mathrm{d}\mu.$$

We have (using [Fresnel integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Generalization))

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\mu e^{-it\mu^{2}/2m}\mathrm{d}\mu\sim \frac{im}{t}.$$

Hence

$$I(t)\sim\frac{im}{t}e^{-imt}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: On the last integral, for the method of stationary phase, if you evaluate $f(c)$ you get 0 which makes the approximation 0, is there something I'm missing on why that doesn't happen

Comment: @JoshuaPasa Like I said, "unforgivably handwavy but faster". Remember, the point is to show $I(t)\sim\exp(-imt)$. Besides, if you feel as nervous about it as I do (and I do!), then you can use the Fresnel integral approach. It's a good idea to verify "dodgy methods" by several means, especially in QFT.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just going through Peskin and Schroeder's book myself, and I couldn't get the method of stationary phase to work it out.

Comment: @JoshuaPasa As an aside, if you are self-studying QFT, I would encourage you to start with Brian Hatfield's "Quantum Field Theory of Point Particles And Strings". Contrary to its title, its overwhelmingly about vanilla QFT with a chapter on strings. It shows all calculations, and discusses functional methods not discussed elsewhere (e.g., the functional Schrodinger equation). It's a good prelude to Peskin & Schroeder, in my opinion.

Comment: I've heard that Peskin and Schroeder is the book everyone uses as it contains a lot of detail. Does Hartfield's book skim over a lot of detail or is it good enough to get a solid understanding of QFT?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa It's good enough to get a solid understanding of QFT. I would highly encourage it, if you are self-studying. Be careful if you get the first edition, it contains a lot of typos. (Alternatively, use it as homework, to double check the calculations, and think of different ways to perform the same calculation.) If you do this, you can return to Peskin and Schroeder, and the first dozen chapters or so (of P&S) will be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Just a note on the third integral.
$$\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_m^\infty dE\sqrt{E^2-m^2}e^{-iEt}.$$
If you don't want to explicitly do the calculation, as in Alex's answer, there is a plausibility argument. In the limit where $t$ is very large, the exponential oscillates very rapidly. The oscillations will cancel each other except in the region where $\sqrt{E^2-m^2}$ has very large slope. In fact, at $E=m$, the slope of this function is infinite. Therefore, we can guess that the integral might be proportional to $e^{-imt}$.

Answer (score 3):

This is just complementary to Alex's answer.

2. For the second integral the book provides an analysis in order to push the contour up to wrap around the upper branch cut. After some manipulation, it gives the following integral
   $$
   \frac{1}{4\pi^2 r}\int_m^\infty d\rho \frac{\rho e^{-\rho r}}{\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}}
   $$
   At the limit $r\rightarrow \infty$, the effect of the exponential suppression due to the factor $e^{-\rho r}$ overwhelms that of the singularity of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}}$ at $m$. As a result, one may roughly treat $\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}}$ as a constant, and this leads to (2.52).